# Selecting rows from values in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I am very new to python and working with pandas to subset a data frame.

I have three tables that I need to work with and the first one looks like the one in below

Master Table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| A0 | john |
| A1 | tim |
| A2 | james |
| A3 | Jane |

the second table I have is below
| id    | Year |
| ---- | ---- |
| A0 | 2019 |
| A1 | 2020   |
| A1 | 2019   |

the third table I have is below
| name    | Year |
| ---- | ---- |
| Jane | 2020  |

With the id's in second table and names in third, I want to subset the first table (Master Table) that matches the id and name from second and third table
And give option that select only from year == 2020

so the output may look like below:
| id       | name  |
| -------- | -------------- |
| A1 | tim     |
| A3 | Jane  |

I am was thinking of solving this problem by using if loops, but could not figure it out

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If need filter master by `id` or by `name` from second `df` use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check membership, conditions are chained by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
master[master['id'].isin(df1['id']) | master['name'].isin(df2['name'])]
```

EDIT: For filter rows by `Year`s add:

```
id1 = df1.loc[df1['Year'] == 2000, 'id']
name2 = df2.loc[df2['Year'] == 2000, 'name']
master[master['id'].isin(id1) | master['name'].isin(name2)]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick help, I realized that I made mistake in the post, so I edited it and could you take a look at it?

Comment: Thank you so much!! can I ask you one more question?
If the second and third table had same ID's and Name but "Year" instead of "date",
Then, will this work?
master[master['id'].isin(df1[['Year' == 2020]].['id']) | master['name'].isin(df2[['Year' == 2020]].['name'])]

Comment: @Python123new - Sure, come on ;)

Comment: just edited the question, if you have hard time understanding the question, I can edit the post itself